# iText upgrade from 2.1 to 5.x, how to convert XmlPeer and XmlParser?

Tags: java, itext

In upgrading our iText (this is Java) from 2.1 to 5.x, I'm finding some old code that uses a map of XmlPeer objects to generate a pdf from a xml template and replace template sections on the way.

Generally it looks like:

```
Document document = new Document();
HashMap tagmap = new HashMap();
XmlPeer peer = new XmlPeer(ElementTags.ITEXT, "tag");
peer.setContent("value");
tagmap.put(peer.getAlias(), peer);
...
XmlParser.parse(document, blah, tagmap);
```

There seems to be no equivalent to this in 5.0.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Bruno decided to yank out much of the Older Stuff wholesale.

The closest equivalent is HTMLWorker... but hey, that's what XSLT is *for* right?

Comment: I wish it were that easy in this case.  This code is taking arbitrary content from a user, which has xml-like <tag/> which it was depending on iText to do.  I've never taken data from a hashmap and used XSLT to do the replacement.  Is that possible?

Comment: Some of the other devs just released an `XMLWorker` demo.  Perhaps you'll find it helpful.  http://lowagie.com/xmlworker and http://demo.itextsupport.com/

Comment: Looking at the code at the bottom of the [xmlworker's doc page](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/doc.html), I see that you can indeed specify your own tag names and their meaning... maybe style names too, though that's unclear.

Comment: Styling your tags with CSS will be possible if your tags have style attribute, or if you define the tag in your CSS, or if you give it a css-class in class attribute.

Comment: Balder?!  Didn't realize you were on SO too.  Small world.